# Error in Oracle APEX 5.0 ORA-06550: line 5, column 9: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "START" when expecting one of the following: ) ,

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am using the below code in Oracle APEX to update and insert a row into the table, but getting an error when I try to update the data. It occurs at the line "`if :EFFECTIVE_START_DATE >= SYSDATE then`" . If I remove this "if" condition it works fine.

```
DECLARE

BEGIN

   IF :EFFECTIVE_START_DATE >= SYSDATE
   THEN
      xxxxx.pkg.UPDATE_DATA ( :APP_USER,
                             SYSDATE,
                             NVL ( :COMPANY_CODE, NULL),
                             NVL ( :COST_CENTER, NULL),
                             :USER_NAME,
                             TO_DATE ( :EFFECTIVE_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'));

      xxxxx.pkg.UPDATE_DATA.INSERT_DATA (NVL ( :COMPANY_CODE, NULL),
                                         NVL ( :COST_CENTER, NULL),
                                         :USER_NAME,
                                         :USER_NAME_NEW,
                                         :EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,
                                         :EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
                                         :APP_USER,
                                         SYSDATE,
                                         :APP_USER,
                                         SYSDATE);
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      Raise_Application_Error (-20002, 'ERROR= ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

> ORA-06550: line 5, column 9: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "START"
>   when expecting one of the following: ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod
>   remainder not rem =>  <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or
>   like like2 like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset

Comment: Is the name of the second procedure you call correct ?  You seem to have an extra 'level' in there.

Comment: Is your package called 'START'? The part which you have XX'd out?

Comment: btw that exception hander does nothing useful and would be better removed. If you want it to include the existing error stack, pass the third parameter as `true` instead of concatenating `sqlerrm`.

Comment: What is the value of `:effective_start_date`? What is at column 9 (as referred to in the error message)?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the comments, you appear to have included periods `.` as part of your package and procedure names. If that is the case, you need to use double quotes `"` to make sure Oracle knows that that is part of the name like this:

```
"START.pkg"."UPDATE_DATA"
```

and

```
"START.pkg"."UPDATE_DATA.INSERT_DATA"
```

assuming those are their names.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  IF :EFFECTIVE_START_DATE >= SYSDATE THEN
    XXXXX.PKG.UPDATE_DATA(
                          :APP_USER,
                          SYSDATE,
                          NVL ( :COMPANY_CODE, NULL),
                          NVL ( :COST_CENTER, NULL),
                          :USER_NAME,
                          TO_DATE ( :EFFECTIVE_START_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                         );

    XXXXX.PKG.INSERT_DATA(
                          NVL ( :COMPANY_CODE, NULL),
                          NVL ( :COST_CENTER, NULL),
                          :USER_NAME,
                          :USER_NAME_NEW,
                          :EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,
                          :EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
                          :APP_USER,
                          SYSDATE,
                          :APP_USER,
                          SYSDATE
                         );
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20002, 'ERROR= ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```